# QAWC gsl - could not integrate function

Tags: gsl

I've got such a piece of code:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

double func1(double x, void* params) {
   return 1/(x-1);
}

int main() {
   int num = 100;
   gsl_integration_workspace *workspace = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc(num); 
   double result, error;    
   double alpha;    
   alpha = 1;
   gsl_function F;  
   F.function = &func1; 
   F.params = &alpha;   
   double a, b;
   a=0; 
   b=2;
   double err1= 0;  
   double err2 = 1e-7;
   gsl_integration_qawc (&F, a, b, 1.0, err1, err2, num, workspace,&result, &error);

   printf("Function QAWC - Cauchy Principal value\n");
   printf("Result: %f\n", result);
   printf("Error: %f\n", error);

   result = 0; 
   gsl_integration_workspace_free(workspace);   //zwolnienie pamięci dla całkowania
   return 0;
}
```

I thought that it'll deal with such a kind of function, but I get the "could not integrate function" error. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that hard. Simply the function which will be calculated has a form F(x)=g(x)*w(x), where g(x) is a function which user has to define. w(x) is made using c parameter and has form: w(x)=1/(x-c). So if we want to compute principal value for function f(x)=1/(x-1) func1 should be:

```
double func1(double x, void* params) {
   return 1;
}
```

And parameter c (4. parameter of function gsl_integration_qawc) sholud be 1.